# SQL - Grouping.... null characters in some registries

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have the following table. (This table is a result from a query that gathers information from 2 tables):

```
ID          Resnum          Car         Store_ID            Currency    
--------    ------------    ---------   -----------------   --------------
1561        R01525AX        (null)      (null)              USD
1561        R01525AX        Honda       (null)              USD
1561        R01525AX        (null)      ATR1654             USD
1561        R01525AX        (null)      (null)              USD
2589        Z7659MBZ        (null)      NINT672             MXN
2589        Z7659MBZ        (null)      (null)              MXN
2589        Z7659MBZ        NISSAN      (null)              MXN
2589        Z7659MBZ        (null)      (null)              MXN
3698        F7871VVS        (null)      (null)              ARG
3698        F7871VVS        (null)      (null)              ARG
3698        F7871VVS        (null)      MOP98645            ARG
4523        CD5437ZZ        (null)      (null)              USD
4523        CD5437ZZ        (null)      (null)              USD
4523        CD5437ZZ        FORD        (null)              USD
4523        CD5437ZZ        (null)      (null)              USD
```

And I'm trying to get the EXPECTED result:

```
ID          Resnum          Car         Store_ID            Currency    
--------    ------------    ---------   -----------------   --------------
1561        R01525AX        Honda       ATR1654             USD
2589        Z7659MBZ        NISSAN      NINT672             MXN
3698        F7871VVS        (null)      MOP98645            ARG
4523        CD5437ZZ        FORD        (null)              USD
```

To tell you the truth, I have no idea how to attack this. Any recommendation will be appreciate it.

I've read something about the COALESCE function, but can't really understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the columns you want to be unique and use the aggregate function `max()` to get the highest value for each group

```
select id, resnum, max(car), max(store_id), currency
from your_table
group by id, resnum, currency
```